# Extract month , calculate and put it in a column

Tags: sql, postgresql

I have query problem. I use postgresql!
I need to extract month from a date and get the total of the month then put it in a column

```
table qwe 
----------------------------
tipe    | dateissued
----------------------------
a      | 8/12/2013
b      | 8/12/2013 
c      | 8/12/2013
d      | 9/12/2013
```

the result I need is

```
----------------------------
tipe   | month | totalMonth
----------------------------
a      | 8     | 2 
b      | 8     | 2
c      | 8     | 2
d      | 9     | 2
```

"2" in total month I get it from 8 & 9

Query I've done so far

```
select tipe ,  extract(month from dateissued),
  count( extract(month from dateissued)) over() as totalMonth
from qwe
group by tipe,dateissued
```

http://sqlfiddle.com/#!12/fa8d4/6/0

Comment: A window function would come to mind, but you want a DISTINCT count, which is not implemented for window functions (yet). So, Chis is right.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need another select to count the distinct months:

```
SELECT tipe, 
       Extract(month FROM dateissued), 
       (SELECT Count(DISTINCT( Extract(month FROM dateissued) )) AS totalMonth 
        FROM   qwe) 
FROM   qwe 
GROUP  BY tipe, 
          dateissued;
```

SQL Fiddle: [SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!12/fa8d4/27)